# DS4 connected to PC via bluetooth makes bluetooth devices disconnect

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth, xinput

I've been using DS4Windows for a while now.

Recently I bought a new controller because my old one stopped charging (faulty USB).
When I connect the new controller to PC via bluetooth and launch DS4Windows, a lot of weird things start happening.

- Galaxy Buds+ disconnect and reconnect all the time.
- AKG Y600NC stops working (turns off, unable to turn back on unless I connect USB)

Both devices are working perfectly when connected to other devices (so the AKG doesn't have a dead battery).

I though maybe DS4Windows was acting out, so I uninstalled the driver, restarted and installed InputMapper 1.7 to give that a shot. Sadly, the behavior is the same. I'm starting to think the problem is the XInput API. Maybe it has something to do with the audio capabilities of the controller?

Any idea about how I can troubleshoot this further?

I know the X570 is a bit of a problem child at the moment, so here are my specs:

```
OS: Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
Version: 10.0.19042 Build 19042
System Model: X570 AORUS MASTER
Processor: AMD Ryzen 9 5900X 12-Core Processor, 3701 Mhz, 12 Core(s), 24 Logical Processor(s)
Bios version: Version/Date  American Megatrends International, LLC. F33j, 23/04/2021
GPU: RTX 3080
SMBios version: 3.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Given time everyone will be able to answer their own question :) I finally figured it out.

If you google DS4Windows you'll find [Jays2Kings's version 1.4.52](https://github.com/Jays2Kings/DS4Windows/releases). Which is not maintained anymore (so I heard). So I uninstalled the driver, restarted and installed the new [version from Ryochan](https://github.com/Ryochan7/DS4Windows/releases).

Suddenly all my problems went away (well, the ones related to my controller at least).
Not as exiting as I hoped it would be, but there you have it. Hope it helps someone.